# Where to store bike in the city?

Tags: bicycle

I recently moved to a new apartment in Aveiro, Portugal, and I have no garage to store my bike. What is the best place to store it (during nights and entire weekends)?

There are no nearby bike-holders (not sure if this is a word?) nearby, I live on the 3rd floor (and there's no elevator, so it is hard for me or my gf to carry) and the landlady says the bike takes too much space in the entrance hall.

Should I just lock it to a lamp post? Being in the middle of the sidewalk for days seems like an inappropriate idea. I also thought of putting it in the garage of the building on the other side of the road, but I'm not sure that's legal. Is my only option to just carry it up and down everytime?

Comment: Why not just ask the garage?

Comment: Safer than leaving it on the street - wouldn't last the day where I live :/ ... though in order to qualify as a life hack, someone's going to have to think up something pretty fiendish... else it's not a life hack.

Comment: I wonder if your landlady will allow you to build you a winch at one of your windows. That,type like at a helicopter. That would be a neat project with a Raspberry Pi, you could operate it with your smartphone. You could also use it to carry heavier stuff up and down.

Comment: The garage is closed off, id have to ask for a key, which they wont grant me. The other option is to leave it just outside the door, but theres nothing to lock it to

Comment: If you want to keep your stuff, your only option is to lug it up and down the stairs and store it inside your home.  Anything else risks it being stolen or damaged, and leaving it outside will accelerate deterioration like rust on your bike.   Perhaps you would benefit from a light folding bike ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you speak to a neighbour and politely ask them if you could store your bike in their garage or their yard. Maybe you could offer them something in exchange.